# javascript type error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I Use the following javascript i got the error in line of
 **var cbPOC = row.cells(row.cells.length - 2).getElementsByTagName('input')[0];**.error is **TypeError: Property 'cells' of object # is not a function**

```
function sss(tableName)
{
var table = getServerObject(tableName);
var cell,row; 
for (var i = 2; i < table.rows.length - 1; i++)
{
    row = table.rows[i];

    var cbPOC = row.cells(row.cells.length - 2).getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    if (cbPOC.checked) continue;
    {
     //Something
    }

}
```

Comment: What gets returned from `getServerObject()`?

Comment: table elements.I need to loop the all table elements

Comment: @user all the tables? Then, you need to loop through the tables to access each one individually.

Comment: @Jack does it matter? He is calling `.cells` as a function and won't even accept the solution... cv'ing...

Comment: @Esailija it mattered before OP's first response to the answer, since `getServerObject()` doesn't seem to suggest it's just a DOM table =p

Comment: @Jack good point =D I was just looking at the properties which suggest  table element

Answer (score 2):

`row.cells(row.cells.length - 2)` should be `row.cells[row.cells.length - 2]`

try.

Comment: No It was not working...If I use like this I have the same Error

Comment: It is not possible you are getting `is not a function` after this edit because you are trying to use `()` on cells which is `function` call in javascript. You sure you are getting the same error? Refresh your browser cache r something if you load your script from external file